# Yii redirect after update in JQM

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, yii

So i have an update function in JQM linked too Yii, when I comment this section out of the controller I get a blank screen

```
        $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

How can I get this to redirect to another page? example #success?